Need help understanding this floating point magic
I need to reimplement this C# function in a different language but have trouble understanding it's inner workings.
Source
public static float NextFloatRange(float min, float max)
    {
        return (min - max) * ((float)(XORShift() << 9) / 0xFFFFFFFF) + max;
    }

What I don't understand is the division here, what exactly happens here? Is the hexadecimal constant a float, an integer? I think I understand so far that we are supposed to end in a value between 0.0 and 1.0 in that bracket, but how we end up with that I don't understand.

This smells like a non-experts attempt to create a random number generator, which rarely ends well .....

@MitchWheat Actually, I am attempting to predict the linked random number generator. Nothing dangerous is going to happen if I fail. I have to reimplement it to be able to generate predictions based on what I hope will be the original random seed when I'm done. Maybe I'm wrong, but given this working prng, it seems like the only thing that can go wrong for the integer part is I trip up with negative number shifts (my target language only has signed ints).

This part presumably generates a random 32-bit number:
XORShift() << 9

0xFFFFFFFF is the max value for a 32-bit number, so the division is creating a value between 0.0 and 1.0. Hexadecimal is basically only used to represent integers; a 32-bit integer in this case. The previous result is presumably also an integer, so it is converted to a float to avoid integer division being performed and the result always being zero. The result of that division is then scaled and shifted based on the desired range.
The fact that that code uses min - max and + max rather than max - min and + min may mean that I'm slightly off with the range of the subcalculation - there may be some two's-complement stuff going on - but the principle holds: generate the number, divide to create a proportion, multiply to scale and add to shift.

Makes sense, thanks. Now how in the world do I translate this to signed integers? Dividing by -1 isn't going to have the same effect.

Wait I'm dumb, I can just express that part as float.
